# combobox.text changed when set combobox.dropdown = true

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

As the title, I create this combobox with this feature:

When combobox text changed, dropdown will be set to true, so that customer can see what they can choose.

But on the first time combobox.text change, and combobox.dropdown is set from dropdown = false to true, Combobox.text changed to the first item in combobox.items list.

What can i do to prevent combobox.text changed when set combobox.dropdown to true?

```
    If Len(cbb(Index).Text) < 4 Then  'cbb(Index).Text = "1" on this line
        cbb(Index).DroppedDown = True   'when cbb(Index).DroppedDown is set form false to true, cbb(Index).Text = "1110" - the first item appear on dropdownbox.items list
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I want it dropdown without change its Text. What is the best way to achive this?

Thank you!

Comment: The `ComboBox` control has an autocomplete feature built in. Why not use that?

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney  it worked! But i am still want to know the answer about this problem, is this the feature and do we have anyway to prevent this?